# Random variable having density proportional to a function

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, density-function

*Let $X$ be a random variable with density proportional to a function $g(x)$, where $g$ is a function $g(x):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
|x|^{-n};|x|\geq 1\\ 0; |x|<1 
\end{matrix}\right.$ that depends on a positive integer $n\geq 2$.*

- *Write thorougly the density of $X$ for a generic value $n\geq 2$.*
- *Draw the density for $n=3$ and $n=10$.*
- *Determine for which values of $n$ exists $\mathbb{E}[X]$.*
- *Determine for which values of $n$ exists $\mathbb{Var}[X]$.*

---

I've never seen an exercise like this. I'm having a trouble understanding how approach the problem with a random variable that depends on a function (especially a function with module). Could you give me some hints on how to start?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As the comments pointed out, I misread the question, and thought that $g(x)$ was the density. However, the density $p(x)$ is in fact $Cg(x)$, where $C$ is a constant to be determined. I have edited the answer appropriately.

As $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)dx = 1$ and $g(x)$ is even, we see that 
\begin{align}
1 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Cg(x)dx \\
&= 2C\int_1^{\infty}|x|^{-n}dx \\
&= 2C\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}\biggr|_1^{\infty} \\
&= \frac{2C}{n-1}\\
\end{align}

(the last step is valid as $n>2$)

So, $C = \frac{n-1}{2}$, and so $p(x) = \frac{n-1}{2}g(x)$.

Now, we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(x)dx \\
&=\frac{n-1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xg(x)dx
\end{align}

As $g(x)$ is even, $xg(x)$ is odd.

So, $$\int_{-a}^{a}xg(x)dx = 0$$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and hence we get $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$.

Thus, we also get $\mathbb{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[(X-E[X])^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$

Now, as $g(x)$ is even, so is $x^2g(x)$.

Thus

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Var}[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2p(x)dx \\
&= 2\frac{n-1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}x^2g(x)dx \\
&= (n-1)\int_1^{\infty}x^2|x|^{-n}dx \\
&= (n-1)\int_1^{\infty}x^{2-n}dx \\
& = (n-1)\frac{x^{3-n}}{3-n}\biggr|_1^{\infty} \\
\end{align}

The last term exists only when the power of $x<0$.

So, $\mathbb{Var}[X]$ exists when $n>3$, and $\mathbb{Var}[X]=\frac{n-1}{n-3}$

Comment: Really Thanks for your answer. I've only a question. Is it formally correct write $1=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}Cg(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{1}Cg(x)dx+\int_{1}^{+\infty}Cg(x)dx=C\int_{-\infty}^{1}-|x|^{-n}dx+C\int_{1}^{+\infty}|x|^{-n}dx=$ $-C\int_{1}^{+\infty}-|x|^{-n}dx+C\int_{1}^{+\infty}|x|^{-n}=C\int_{1}^{+\infty}|x|^{-n}dx+C\int_{1}^{+\infty}|x|^{-n}dx=2C\int_{1}^{+\infty}|x|^{-n}=...$

Comment: It should be $C\int^{-1}_{-\infty} |x|^ndx$, and not $C\int^{1}_{-\infty} -|x|^ndx$

Comment: Thanks again! But for $x<0$ it shouldn't be $C\int_{-\infty}^{-1}0dx$?

Comment: Nope. $g(x) = |x|^{-n}$ for $|x|\ge 1$, which implies that $g(x) = |x|^{-n}$ for $x\le -1$

Comment: You mean that for $|x|\geq 1 \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
x\geq 1,x>0\\ 
-x\geq 1 \Rightarrow x\leq -1,x<0
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
|x|^{-n},x\geq 1\\ 
|x|^{-n},x\leq -1
\end{matrix}\right.$?

Comment: Yup! That is exactly what I want to say.

Comment: Really really thanks, now it's clear!